# PHP array get item value gives only first char

Tags: php, foreach

I have this kind of Array

```
    Array
(
    [year] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2019
        )

    [user] => usermail@gmail.com
)
```

The only thing I want is to get the usermail from this array.

it seems simple, but still doesn't work for me. I tried to get it like this:

```
   foreach ($filter as $item) { echo $item['user'];}
```

but this goves mi only the first character of the email, so the result is 'u'.

Comment: Just use `echo $filter['user'];` without the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to iterate, do like below:-

```
echo $filter['user'];
```

Sample output:-https://3v4l.org/Gsmhr

***Note:***

In-case you have multidimensional array then you have to use `foreach()`: https://3v4l.org/9TBeG

Comment: ahh, seems I had a hard day :) Trying to complicate things. Thank you, works as expected.

Comment: @wotan  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 2):

As array contains only one element. So, there is no need to iterate the loop. You may get the value of user directly like :

`echo $filter['user'];`

Suppose, you have multiple value within the same array, you may have to iterate the loop if your array is look like below:

```
array(
    [0] => array(
            [year] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2019
                )

            [user] => usermail@gmail.com
        ),
    [1] => array(
            [year] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2019
                )

            [user] => usermail@gmail.com
        )
)
```